# iTextSharp sign verify fails even if acrobat verify that sign without error

Tags: c#, itext, sign

I'm using iTextSharp 5.4.2 and on a sign that Acrobat verify as a correct and not corrupted sign I get that the sign is not verified (here is a [sample](http://db.tt/Mvg1n2Fo)).

I debugged source code and I found that even if the RSAData in the sign was a SHA1 of the content (20 bytes) the messageDigest is created for a SHA256 and the `verifyRSAdata = Arrays.AreEqual(msgDigestBytes, RSAdata)` obiously fails.
*In my opinion the "error" is in PdfPKCS7.cs at line 335*

The sign was created with Filter /Adobe.PPKMS and SubFilter /adbe.pkcs7.sha1

What's wrong ?
Could someone take a look at code to fix it ?

Thank you
Domenico

Comment: Please provide a sample to check. But be aware that the use of **adbe.pkcs7.sha1** has not been recommended at least since PDF became an ISO standard in 2008. It furthermore most likely will be deprecated in the upcoming PDF-2. standard.

Comment: Deprecated for creation, that is, not for verification. It would help if the OP identified the faulty code he found while debugging (class file, line number).

Comment: In my opinion the "error" is in PdfPKCS7.cs at line 335.

Comment: Here is a demo pdf on which I get the error: [link](http://db.tt/Mvg1n2Fo)

Comment: I've looked at the code: http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/575/tree/trunk/src/core/iTextSharp/text/pdf/security/PdfPKCS7.cs and linke 335 is a curly bracket. However, line 334 is `encContDigest = GetHashClass();` and the `GetHashClass()` method seems to get the algoritm from the PDF file. Are you sure we're talking about the same iTextSharp version?

Comment: I'm working on 5.4.2 version. I gave you the line reference using VS2010 that start from first line in .cs file (`using System`). The "error" is in `messageDigest = GetHashClass();` that not consider the size of hash memorized in the sign.

Comment: The new release 5.4.3 fixes this error ?

Comment: I've taken a closer look at the problem, and there's something I don't understand. When examining the signature bytes, asking it for the hashing algorithm, we get 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1 which corresponds with SHA256. However, when looking at the Subfilter, we see that you're using adbe.pkcs7.sha1 which only supports SHA1. Is it possible you signed the PDF using iTextSharp defining a combination that isn't allowed according to the PDF reference?

Comment: Based on the Document properties, I assume that you've signed the document with iTextSharp 5.4.2. I don't make the C# port, but in the Java version, we've made it *impossible* (or rather: very hard) for people to sign a document using the *deprecated* **adbe.pkcs7.sha1** subfilter. This sub filter should no longer be used. The use of SHA1 is no longer allowed in many countries and **adbe.pkcs7.sha1** will be deprecated in ISO-32000-2.

How did you sign that PDF, and why did you use a sub filter that shouldn't be used anymore?